# How to get debug logs in runtime?

Tags: android

Debug console in Android Studio prints me these messages:

```
W/ViewRootImpl[LauncherSettingsActivity]: Dropping event due to no window focus: MotionEvent { action=ACTION_MOVE, actionButton=0, id[0]=0, x[0]=154.80649, y[0]=462.0374, toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0, metaState=0, flags=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1, historySize=0, eventTime=598901019, downTime=598899893, deviceId=5, source=0x1002 }
W/ViewRootImpl[LauncherSettingsActivity]: Dropping event due to no window focus: MotionEvent { action=ACTION_MOVE, actionButton=0, id[0]=0, x[0]=157.665, y[0]=464.89352, toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0, metaState=0, flags=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1, historySize=1, eventTime=598901037, downTime=598899893, deviceId=5, source=0x1002 }
W/ViewRootImpl[LauncherSettingsActivity]: Dropping event due to no window focus: MotionEvent { action=ACTION_MOVE, actionButton=0, id[0]=0, x[0]=145.26581, y[0]=451.9532, toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0, metaState=0, flags=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1, historySize=1, eventTime=598900932, downTime=598899893, deviceId=5, source=0x1002 }
W/ViewRootImpl[LauncherSettingsActivity]: Dropping event due to no window focus: MotionEvent { action=ACTION_MOVE, actionButton=0, id[0]=0, x[0]=146.27205, y[0]=455.41583, toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0, metaState=0, flags=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1, historySize=1, eventTime=598900950, downTime=598899893, deviceId=5, source=0x1002 }
W/ViewRootImpl[LauncherSettingsActivity]: Dropping event due to no window focus: MotionEvent { action=ACTION_MOVE, actionButton=0, id[0]=0, x[0]=147.81523, y[0]=456.0499, toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0, metaState=0, flags=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1, historySize=0, eventTime=598900966, downTime=598899893, deviceId=5, source=0x1002 }
W/ViewRootImpl[LauncherSettingsActivity]: Dropping event due to no window focus: MotionEvent { action=ACTION_MOVE, actionButton=0, id[0]=0, x[0]=152.30963, y[0]=459.04367, toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0, metaState=0, flags=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1, historySize=1, eventTime=598900984, downTime=598899893, deviceId=5, source=0x1002 }
...
```

Is there any way to access these logs in runtime? I would like to get MotionEvents from logs and dispatch them manually to an activity, like that: `someActivity.dispatchTouchEvent(myMotionEvent)`

Comment: Why would you need access to the logs, do you mean you need access to a specific functionality and when that functionality, or the touch event in this case happens?

Comment: @gtxtreme The problem is that my touch-events are not coming to the activity by some reason, I can only see them in the debug console. I would like to set some "log listener" and get touch-events in String format, parse them to get MotionEvents and dispatch. It doesn't seem like a good solution, but this is the only workaround I see

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run logcat in your app

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("logcat -d -s -vtime *");
```

Now your logs will be available via the process.getInputStream()

You may also specify other flags for logcat command line

https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/logcat

PS. Though I think an attempt to use the logs within application to manage motion events is a really bad idea.